# How to section a element with selenium & Appium that does not have a unique id, class, package, or resource id?

Tags: javascript, android, selenium, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to detect if I get the expect response from a text message. so I need to access the text view of the received text. the problem I'm having is I cant figure out a way to let the driver know I need the received text rather than the sent text.

[this first image of the ui selector shows that the sent text is highlighted here it shows the id, class, package, and resourse-id (which is out of frame)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfYyn.png)

[in the second image of the ui selector shows that the received text is highlighted here it shows the id, class(out of frame), package, and resourse-id (which is out of frame)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKqI.png)

all the attributes values match expect for the text value. how can i let appium know which one i need to check? 
i was thinking something that accessed a element within another element, code id assume would be something like this:

```
await driver.waitForElementById('com.android.mms:id/msg_list_item_recv', 30000, function (err, data) {})
        .elementById('com.android.mms:id/text_view', function (err, data){})
        .textPresent('key text value', function (err, data) {});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you can ask developers to update id of send text it will be best to do this, as currently there is same id for sent and received text . If this is not possible you can try this .

@FindBy(id = "com.android.mms:id/text_view")
    private List<WebElement> messagelist;

for (int i=0;i<messagelist.size();i++) 
{ 
    if(messagelist.get(i).gettext().contentEquals("sendtext"))
    {
       // then i+1 is your received text
        messagelist.get(i+1).gettext().contentEquals("recievedText")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks shiv, i couldn't do exactly that for my code but thanks to your help i was able to do the same with the modified code below:                  
 ```var recieveExpectedResponse = false;
 await driver.elementsById('com.android.mms:id/text_view', function (err, elements) {
  elements.forEach(function (element) {
   element.text().then(function (text) {
    if (text === "#What ever response youre expecting#") {
     //if the expected response was recieved this will keep the test from failing
     recieveExpectedResponse = true;
    }
   });
  })
 })```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to detect if message is received (left) or sent (right) is to compare with their bounds...

For my example I will use these two bounds:

[Received message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjHiJ.jpg)

[Sent message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGr52.jpg)

In Xpath with my example could be:

```
"//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='com.android.mms:id/msg_list_item_recv' and contains(@bounds, '[163,')]"
```

If you have an element at [163,100][100,100] everything will be ok. But... The problem with this method is that if you have an element at [100,100][163,100] it will detect it as received when is not... So the next method could be better because there is no option...

Another way to get just left messages could be:

```
"//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='com.android.mms:id/msg_list_item_recv' and not(contains(@bounds, '][942,'))]"
```

In the other hand this will return any textview that NOT contains "][942," so there can not be mistakes

Let me know if worked. I do it this way to know it.